# Question about using vBulletin with an ASP.NET based website

Tags: php, asp.net

How to integrate the [vBulletin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBulletin) forums users with an existing ASP.NET site that has its own users and login, and to maintain the session between the two sites, so when a user logs in, he/she stays logged in when browsing the forum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but efforts doesn't worth it I'd say.
Too much of dirty handwork while you're looking for a few mouse clicks - dont' ya? ;)

Either forget cross-site authorization or find yourself NET-based forum.

Comment: I actually don't have a choice..HAVE to use vBulletin :/

Comment: @happy Well actually your NET site have to have just access to the database used by vBulletin. And use it's users and sessions tables.

Answer (score 1):

Install the vBulletin LDAP auth plugin, and get someone from the ASP admin side to setup LDAP server - whatever it may authenticate against - a custom DB, or AD.

Done.

Comment: Forgot to mention; second part of this seamless integration is NTLM. There are plenty of details here that need resolution, but, overall it's doable.